# mobile navigation click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a little help that figuring out that js function. I want to make the mobile navigation "li" onclick function .slideUp. Could anyone help me to figure it out please. thanks again.

```js
<!-- /#js -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nav-mobile").html($("#nav-main").html());
        $("#nav-trigger span").click(function(){
            if ($("nav#nav-mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
                $("nav#nav-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $(this).removeClass("open");
            } else {
                $("nav#nav-mobile ul").addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
                $(this).addClass("open");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!-- /#html -->
<header>
<div id="main">
<div class="container">
  <div id="nav-trigger"> <span></span> </div>
  <nav id="nav-main">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#editorial">Advertorial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bridal">Bridal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#celebrity">Celebrities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fashion">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#styling">Clips</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tv">TV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav id="nav-mobile"></nav>
  </header>
  <!-- /#top-bar -->
```

Comment: Did you write this code by yourself? If so, you should understand what it does. If it was written by someone else, ask this "someone".

Answer (score 0):

The principle is : 
- when you click a li :
1/ it hides all 
2/ it show up one ("expanded")

Your code is strange, in that extent : slidedown & up seems inverted.

You miss the CSS code, which manages UI for that list.